# Changing table row color using a property that would not be visible in any column

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I need to change the table row color using a property that would not be visible in any column of a `tableview`. I did the following:

1. create a model class `Person` (`serialNumber`, `first`, `last`).
2. create an observableList of `Person` using an extractor.
3. create two tableviews(`tableview1`, `tableview2`) and one `listview` that all sharing the same data.
4. `tableview1` has a `serialCol1` column with a visible property set to
       false.

I want to change `tableview1` row color  using  the `serialNumber` property that is bound to a column in a `tableview2`.

**Here is the complete program:**

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

/**
 *
 * @author kachna
 */
public class Extractor extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person> tableView1 = new TableView<>();
    private final TableView<Person> tableView2 = new TableView<>();
    private final ListView<Person> listView = new ListView<>();
    //observable list with extractor
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(p -> new Observable[]{p.serialNumberProperty(), p.firstProperty(), p.lastProperty()});

    static class Person {

        final IntegerProperty serialNumber;
        final StringProperty first;
        final StringProperty last;

        public Person(int serialNumber, String first, String last) {
            this.first = new SimpleStringProperty(first);
            this.last = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
            this.serialNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(serialNumber);
        }

        public IntegerProperty serialNumberProperty() {
            return serialNumber;
        }

        public StringProperty firstProperty() {
            return first;
        }

        public StringProperty lastProperty() {
            return last;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" + "first=" + first.get() + ", last=" + last.get() + '}';
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView2, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        initTableViews();
        initListView();
        getData();
        Label label1 = new Label("TableView 1");
        label1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24px;\n"
                + "-fx-font-weight: bold;");
        Label label2 = new Label("TableView 2");
        label2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24px;\n"
                + "-fx-font-weight: bold;");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(label1, tableView1,label2, tableView2);
        root.setCenter(vBox);
        root.setRight(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void initTableViews() {
        // first table view 
        tableView1.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView1.setEditable(true);
        tableView1.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Person>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    if (item.serialNumber.get() % 2 == 0) {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
                    } else {
                        setStyle(" ");
                    }
                } else {
                    setStyle(" ");
                }
            }

        });

        TableColumn<Person, Number> serialCol1 = new TableColumn<>("Serial Number");
        serialCol1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().serialNumberProperty());
        serialCol1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));

        // make the serialCol1 column invisible
        serialCol1.setVisible(false);
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstCol1 = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstCol1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstProperty());
        firstCol1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastCol1 = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastCol1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastCol1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastProperty());
        tableView1.getColumns().addAll(serialCol1, firstCol1, lastCol1);
        tableView1.setItems(data);

        // second table view  
        tableView2.setEditable(true);
        tableView2.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        TableColumn<Person, Number> serialCol = new TableColumn<>("Serial Number");
        serialCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().serialNumberProperty());
        serialCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstCol2 = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstCol2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstProperty());
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastCol2 = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastCol2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastCol2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastProperty());
        tableView2.getColumns().addAll(serialCol, firstCol2, lastCol2);
        tableView2.setItems(data);
    }

    private void initListView() {
        //list view 

        listView.setCellFactory(list -> new ListCell<Person>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);
                if (!empty && value != null) {
                    if (value.serialNumber.get() % 2 == 0) {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
                    } else {
                        setStyle(" ");
                    }
                    setText(String.format("%s %s %s", value.serialNumber.get(), value.firstProperty().get(), value.lastProperty().get()));
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                    setStyle(" ");
                }

            }
        });

        listView.setItems(data);
    }

    private void getData() {
        data.setAll(IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Person(i, "first" + i, "last" + i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Problem:**

- the style of `tableview1` doesn't change instantly after applying a
  change. I have to scroll hrough the rows to see the style updated. the style of the `listview` is changed instantly without any problems.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `updateItem` method is not bound to the property lifecycle of its item ( an item must not be an Observable ), but rather gets called by the View (ListView/TableView) whenever it deems it necessary to update the data representation. When you scroll a Row off screen it gets nulled ( I assume for performance reasons ) and updated again when in screen.

What you want to do is to bind the `styleProperty`of the row to its items `serialNumberProperty`like so:

```
tableView1.setRowFactory( tv -> new TableRow<Person>()
    {
      @Override
      protected void updateItem( final Person item, final boolean empty )
      {
        super.updateItem( item, empty );

        if ( !empty && item != null )
        {

          this.styleProperty().bind( Bindings.createStringBinding( () ->
          {
            if ( item.serialNumber.get() % 2 == 0 )
            {
              return "-fx-background-color: orange;";
            }
            return " ";
          } , item.serialNumberProperty() ) );

        }
        else
        {
          /*
           * As per comment in the Cell API
           */
          setText( null );
          setGraphic( null );

          this.styleProperty().unbind();

          setStyle( " " );
        }
      }
    } );
```

I also recommend consulting the documentation of `javafx.scene.control.Cell#updateitem(...)` as it is marked as "Expert API".

[Link to full example.](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/7da3a09c3e693020fd32)

Comment: thanks, it works. I have a question: why the problem doesn't happen for `listview` (the `listview` refreshes without any further binding).

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it is most likely a difference in implementation of `ListCell` and `TableRow`. Maybe you should file this as a bug, since only one of those behaviours can be correct.