# Update row color in TableView using Observable

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I would like to change row color to green when A and B column values are equal and to red if they differ. I completely don't know how to adapt examples found on SO. I add listener? Use `Observable`? I added whole code I prepared for further changes.

sample.fxml:

```
GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" editable="true">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="colA" text="A">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="A"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>

            <TableColumn fx:id="colB" text="B">
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="B"/>
                </cellValueFactory>
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList"/>
        </items>
    </TableView>
</GridPane>
```

RowTest.java:

```
public class RowTest {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty a;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty b;
    private SimpleBooleanProperty validRow;

    public RowTest(int a, int b) {
        this.a = new SimpleIntegerProperty(a);
        this.b = new SimpleIntegerProperty(b);

        this.validRow = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        this.validRow.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> this.a.get() == this.b.get()));
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty aProperty() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a.set(a);
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty bProperty() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(int b) {
        this.b.set(b);
    }

    public boolean isValidRow() {
        return validRow.get();
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty validRowProperty() {
        return validRow;
    }

    public void setValidRow(boolean validRow) {
        this.validRow.set(validRow);
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<RowTest> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RowTest, Integer> colB;
    @FXML
    private ObservableList<RowTest> data;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        populateData();
        setColumnsEditable();
    }

    private void setColumnsEditable() {
        tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<RowTest>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(RowTest item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null) {
                    setStyle("");
                } else if (item.isValidRow()) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: LightGreen; -fx-text-fill: Black;");
                } else if (!item.isValidRow()) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: Red; -fx-text-fill: Black;");
                } else {
                    setStyle("");
                }
            }
        });

        colB.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt.forTableColumn(new IntToStringConverter<Integer>()));
        colB.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<RowTest, Integer> t) -> {
                    ((RowTest) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setB(t.getNewValue());
                });

        data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<RowTest>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends RowTest> c) {
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasUpdated()) {

                   }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateData() {
        data.add(new RowTest(1, 1));
        data.add(new RowTest(1, 0));

        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
}
```

IntToStringConverter.java:

```
public class IntToStringConverter<Integer> extends StringConverter<java.lang.Integer> {

    @Override
    public String toString(java.lang.Integer object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.Integer fromString(String string) {
        return java.lang.Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 275);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt.java:

```
public class TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt<S, T> extends TextFieldTableCell<S, T> {

    protected TextField textField;
    protected boolean isEdit;

    public TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt() {
        this(null);
    }

    public TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt(final StringConverter<T> conv) {
        super(conv);
    }

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn() {
        return forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> forTableColumn(final StringConverter<T> conv) {
        return list -> new TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt<S, T>(conv);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        isEdit = true;
        if (updateTextField()) {
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(this::onFocusChange);
            textField.setOnKeyPressed(this::onKeyPress);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return whether {@link #textField} has been changed
     */
    protected boolean updateTextField() {
        final Node g = getGraphic();
        final boolean isUpd = g != null && textField != g;
        if (isUpd) {
            textField = g instanceof TextField ? (TextField) g : null;
        }
        return isUpd;
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(final T valNew) {
        if (isEditing()) {
            super.commitEdit(valNew);
        } else {
            final TableView<S> tbl = getTableView();
            if (tbl != null) {
                final TablePosition<S, T> pos = new TablePosition<>(tbl, getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn()); // instead of tbl.getEditingCell()
                final TableColumn.CellEditEvent<S, T> ev = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(tbl, pos, TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), valNew);
                Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), ev);
            }
            updateItem(valNew, false);
            if (tbl != null) {
                tbl.edit(-1, null);
            }
            // TODO ControlUtils.requestFocusOnControlOnlyIfCurrentFocusOwnerIsChild(tbl);
        }
    }

    public void onFocusChange(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, final boolean v0, final boolean v1) {
        if (isEdit && !v1) {
            commitEdit(getConverter().fromString(textField.getText()));
        }
    }

    protected void onKeyPress(final KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getCode()) {
            case ESCAPE:
                isEdit = false;
                cancelEdit(); // see CellUtils#createTextField(...)
                e.consume();
                break;
            case TAB:
                if (e.isShiftDown()) {
                    getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
                } else {
                    getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectNext();
                }
                e.consume();
                break;
            case UP:
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectAboveCell();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case DOWN:
                getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectBelowCell();
                e.consume();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How from this place:

```
data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<RowTest>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends RowTest> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasUpdated()) {

            }
        }
    }
});
```

get access to row? So, based on ObservableList item I want get its Row container. I don't know how to do it.

Edit:

This bind was wrong:

```
 this.validRow.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> this.a.get() == this.b.get()));
```

I changed to this:

```
this.validRow.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> this.a.get() == this.b.get(), this.aProperty(), this.bProperty()));
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__ :-)

Comment: Original project compares sum of columns to sum of other columns, I removed everything I could. It is a lot of code, `TextFieldTableCellAutoCmt.java` is not mine, but I also posted it to show how cells are edited. I tried to analyze SO examples, your and James_D, but I have no clue how I can do this.

Comment: Yes, I can remove one `CellFactory` and `OnEditCommit`, no need to use it on both columns. But it is a minor code capacity.

Comment: .. if you say so .. *shrugs

Comment: okay, your binding is wrong: you need to pass in a and b as dependencies, then instantiate the items with an extractor on validRow, then ... you hit a bug in tableRow which is not notified (or not reacting to) changes of type update - look at the other questions around toggling row state, there are hack-arounds (sry, have to run now, will try to come back later ;)

Comment: So, I added this: `data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[]{e.validRowProperty()});`

Comment: now fix the binding (have a look at the api doc of Bindings.createBooleanBinding, it has more than one parameter, how else would it know when the dependencies changed :) Will search for the issue with TableRow later today ..

Comment: Ok, now I get it: `textArea.appendText("\n" + item.validRowProperty().getValue());` shows that boolean value doesn't change after edit. This bind works:  `this.validRow.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> this.a.get() == this.b.get(), this.aProperty(), this.bProperty()));`

Comment: @kleopatra thank you for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves my problem, but I'm not sure if it's a proper solution.

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(e -> new Observable[]{e.validRowProperty()});
```

Found and modified this code here:

[Changing table row color using a property that would not be visible in any column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870803/changing-table-row-color-using-a-property-that-would-not-be-visible-in-any-colum)

```
tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<RowTest>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(final RowTest item, final boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (!empty && item != null) {
            this.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                if (item.isValidRow()) {
                    return "-fx-background-color: green;";
                } else {
                    return "-fx-background-color: red;";
                }
            }, item.validRowProperty()));
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

            this.styleProperty().unbind();

            setStyle(" ");
        }
    }
});
```

and I changed bind in `RowTest`:

```
this.validRow.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    this.a.get() == this.b.get(), this.aProperty(), this.bProperty()));
```

Comment: good, that's possible and covers most (probably all) use-cases nicely :) Personally, I don't like binding of cell properties to item properties (there are corner cases where they might not be cleaned up properly) - but that's just my preference ..

Comment: Can you in free time show any other solutions? More elegant ones?

Comment: elegance is subjective :) An alternive (with the extractor in place) is to override tableRow's isItemChanged to return true if old and new are the same and it's validProperty is different. Don't have the time for a good answer - but experimented a bit, if you are daring see https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/blob/master9/fx8-swingempire/src/stackoverflow/de/swingempire/fx/scene/control/cell/RowStylingUpdate.java